# current direction when the switch is connected

Tags: current

[image]

At first,SW1 and SW2 are open,after ac produce a positive half current to charge the C1,then two switch close at the end of the positive half current.In this moment,the current from capacitor should flow to the inductor,then,what is the correct direction,a or b?

Comment: At the end of the positive half wave the voltage on C1 is zero. If SW1 and 2 are closed at this instant the current in the inductor will be zero. Having two switches is silly. The first one to open and the last one to close will control the circuit. If the supply has source resistance (or impedance) then the situation changes significantly but you haven't shown any.

Comment: how can it possible!the current charge the capacitor,so the end of the positive half current shouldn't be zero

Comment: My mistake. I read it as a voltage source. Since it is a sinusoidal current source the voltage will be peak at the end of the positive half cycle. You can simulate this with the built in CircuitLab editor. There is a time delay contact included that allows you to switch on at some point in your simulation. Use it instead of SW1 and get rid of SW2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a homework question with no workings shown or attempt made to answer it themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is neither a nor b. When the switches close the voltage across the capacitor happens to be 0V, so the capacitor is actually discharged, despite it's been connected to the source for half a period. So technically, in that point no current flows anywhere.

The next instant in time which is when the negative half cycle starts, the capacitor starts charging (in reverse polarity) and the branch with the inductor and resistor also gets current from the source, as in my picture.
[image]

Comment: but when I close the switch in that moment,the capacitor energy should give to the inductor immediately, so which  is the current direction?

Comment: @user162889: Did you make the same mistake as me? It's a current source and not a voltage source.

Comment: No, you don't understand. In that moment when you close the switch, there's no energy in the capacitor. When the wave starts, the capacitor begins charging, but when it reaches the peak at 1/4 of the wave, it begins to discharge until hits 0V which is the moment when you close the switches.

Comment: @Transistor You're right, but as far as I know that doesn't make any difference here.

Comment: Since it's a current source the voltage on C1 will be the integral of the current an will be a sine wave 90° behind the current waveform.

Comment: @user162889 but from this paper:http://rincon-mora.gatech.edu/publicat/cnfs/new16_pzdamp.pdf  The author said that there is energy in the capacitor.see the V. symmetrically predamp charger